# Javascript (vanilla) oninput delay (Timeout not working)

Tags: javascript

today I have a problem with an text input field.
There's a oninput listener on it which fetches
everytime the user types something in data from a database.
The Problem is that the user can't type anything in when the data from
the server is loaded (about 2 seconds). I searched here for this problem, and found
an answer (use setTimeout). This didn't worked for me and I hope someone can help!
Thank you very much!

```
<input type="text" oninput="onText(event)">

let timer;
function onText(event){
 timer = setTimeout(getData(event.target), 200);
}
function getData(elem){
 // Get data
 // Write data to <span>
}
```

Comment: Search for _"debounce"_ or _"throttle"_ and you should find a solution.

Comment: https://codepen.io/wonism/pen/dXgAxE

Comment: not working, tested it

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `setTimeout` needs to be a function, which will actually be called after the specified interval.

`getData(event.target)` is (one presumes) not a function. It's just the result of calling the desired function. Instead you should pass in a function that calls this, as a function expression. Either `function() {getData(event.target);}` or `() => { getData(event.target); }` will work instead.

Comment: Tested it but it's not workin :C (but the performance is a little bit better)